# Storing template abstract classes in std::vector

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to translate some Java code into C++ and I am having some trouble with the type system.

I have a interface/pure virtual class which represents a column in a table, and I want the table to be a vector of these generic columns:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class IColumn {
public:
    virtual const std::string& name() = 0;
    virtual size_t size() = 0;
    virtual T at(size_t idx) = 0;
    virtual std::vector<T> data() = 0;
    virtual ~IColumn() = default;
};

class StringColumn : public IColumn<std::string> {
public:
    StringColumn(std::string name, std::vector<std::string> data)
            : name_(std::move(name)), data_(std::move(data)) {}

    const std::string& name() override { return name_; }
    size_t size() override { return data_.size(); }

    const std::vector<std::string>& data() override { return data_; }
    std::string at(size_t idx) override { return data_[idx]; }

private:
    std::string name_;
    std::vector<std::string> data_;
};

class IntColumn : public IColumn<int> {
public:
    IntColumn(std::string name, std::vector<int> data)
            : name_(std::move(name)), data_(std::move(data)) {}

    const std::string& name() override { return name_; }
    size_t size() override { return data_.size(); }

    const std::vector<int>& data() override { return data_; }
    int at(size_t idx) override { return data_[idx]; }

private:
    std::string name_;
    std::vector<int> data_;
};
```

However, I am having issues when declaring the vector in the `Table` class:

```cpp
class Table {
   std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IColumn>> columns;
};
```

I understand that `IColumn` is a template class, hence it complains about the missing template parameter, however I am not sure how to get around this issue, because the virtual functions `T at()` and `std::vector<T> data()` rely on T.

How could I fix this issue or could someone suggest an alternative design for this API?

EDIT: Using the `std::variant<IntColumn, StringColumn>` with `std::visit` as suggested:

```cpp
for (auto& col: columns_) {
    std::cout << std::visit([](auto&& arg) { return arg.name(); }, col) << '\t';
}
std::cout << '\n';
for (int i = 0; i < this->rowCount(); i++) {
    for (auto& col : columns_) {
       auto v = std::visit([i](auto&& arg) { return arg.at(i); }, col);
       std::cout << v;
    }
}
```

The first `std::visit` works, but the second one doesn't.
Thanks.

Comment: `std::variant<StringColumn , IntColumn>`?

Comment: Your *interface* `IColumn` seems superfluous.

Comment: @Jarod42 So if I had a `std::vector< std::variant<StringColumn, IntColumn> > columns`, how would I generically call the `at()` method of `columns[0]` ?

Comment: Is this a translation of Java code that returns `Object`, a.k.a. "some object of unspecified type"?

Comment: @DrewDormann No, its a `Column<?>` translation

Comment: @alexcons: I don't know Java, but wouldn't you have to know what the `?` is in `Column<?>` to be able to use it? Like, if you're going to conceptually call `at`, you *have to know* at the point when you call it what type you're getting, right? So you have to know what type is stored at that position. So you're not looking at the base class anymore.

Comment: with [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).

Comment: @DrewDormann The Java code is `private final List<Column<?>> columnList`. The `?` is the wildcard type, ie any type will match.

Comment: @alexcons: Yeah, that's not a thing in C++.

Comment: @Jarod42 Could you give an example with std::visit? How would I invoke `columns[0].at(idx)` safely? The documentation seems a bit alien to me

Comment: @alexcons (I don't know Java, but) `List<Column<?>>` means that `columnList` can be a container of that type with `?` replaced by some type, but it doesn't mean that you can have different types stored in the container at the same time, does it? If so, you really want to make the vector polymorphic, not the columns.

Comment: @alexcons: Provide some usages, but for example `std::visit([idx](const auto& column){ std::cout << column.at(idx); }, columns[0]);`.

Comment: @Jarod42 I added an example in the original post.

Comment: @alexcons The second `std::visit` doesn't work because the type of `v` would vary from column to column in the iteration. All parts of the code that dependent on the element type would need to be put inside the lambda passed to `std::visit`.

Comment: @user17732522 Thanks!

Comment: Some background: this translation issue arises because Java generics inherently use type erasure ("boxing"), while C++ templates do not: an `IColumn<std::string>` is fundamentally a different type than `IColumn<int>`. Type erasure in C++ has to be managed explicitly using e.g. `std::variant`/`std::any`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IColumn` seems strange, you can indeed go with template:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Column {
public:
    Column(std::string name, std::vector<T> data) :
       m_name(std::move(name)),
       m_data(std::move(data))
    {}

    const std::string& name() const { return m_name; }
    std::size_t size() const { return m_data.size(); }
    const T& at(size_t idx) const { return m_data.at(idx); }
    std::vector<T>& data() { return m_data; }
private:
    std::string m_name;
    std::vector<T> m_data;
};
```

and `std::variant` in `Table`

```cpp
struct Table
{
   std::vector<std::variant<Column<std::string>, Column<int>>> columns;
};
```

Usage might be similar to

```cpp
Table table;
table.columns.push_back(Column<std::string>("string column", {"data1", "data2", "data3"}));
table.columns.push_back(Column<int>("int column", {4, 8, 15}));

const char* sep = "";
for (auto& col: table.columns) {
    std::visit([&sep](const auto& arg) { std::cout << sep << arg.name(); }, col);
    sep = "\t";
}
std::cout << "\n";
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < table.rowCount(); i++) {
    const char* sep = "";
    for (const auto& col : table.columns) {
        std::visit([i, &sep](const auto& arg) { std::cout << sep << arg.at(i); }, col);
        sep = "\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75739357070e634b)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my approach is suitable for your needs.
Here we add `item_size()` method and return `void*` instead of `T`

```cpp
class IColumn {
public:
    virtual const std::string& name() = 0;
    virtual size_t size() = 0;
    virtual size_t item_size() = 0;
    virtual void* at(size_t idx) = 0;
    virtual void* data() = 0;
    virtual ~IColumn() = default;
};
```

And then implement column with custom types

```cpp
template <class T>
class TColumn : public IColumn {
public:
    TColumn(std::string name, std::vector<T> data) : name_(std::move(name)), data_(std::move(data)) {}

    const std::string& name() override { /* */}
    virtual size_t size() override { /* */ }
    size_t item_size() override {
        return sizeof(T);
    }
    void* at(size_t idx) override {
        return &data_.at(idx);
    }
    void* data() override {
        return data_.data();
    }
private:
    std::string name_;
    std::vector<T> data_;
};
```

And then you can do something like

```cpp
Table t;
std::vector<int> column = { 1, 2, 3 };
t.columns.emplace_back(std::make_unique<TColumn<int>>("name", column));

int item;
void* res = t.columns[0]->at(0);
std::memcpy(&item, res, sizeof(item));

std::cout << item << '\n';
```

Comment: Using a cast and assignment instead of `memcpy` would make it clearer where the caveat is here: That there will be an unsafe cast that must be manually assured to match the actual type of the pointed-to object.